# Using regex to find substring inside another substring

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Using regex, how would one check for ANY portion of a string (substring) within another string(substring)?
For example:

```
str1 = "li_xxxyyy" 
str2 = "123xxxyyy"
```

I need a true response for the xxxyyy variable portion of the string.

I'm looking for **any** portion of str1 found in **any** portion of str2

Comment: what do you mean by portion, strings separated by `_`?

Comment: What should be the result for: `str1="abcxy"; str2="123yx";`?

Comment: `function matchAny(str1, str2, flags){
    return str2.match(new RegExp(str1.split('').join('|'), flags));
  }
  console.log(matchAny('li_xxxyyy', '123xxxyyy', 'ig').join(''));`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that here we would just want to use a capturing group around our desired output and that'd likely solve our problem, with a simple expression such as:

```js
const regex = /(xxxyyy)/gm;
const str = `li_xxxyyy
123xxxyyy
123xxxyyy123xxxyyy
123xxxyyy123`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7y1pQU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

> So again, any portion of str1 found in any portion of str2

You don't need regex tbh, it would be simpler and faster to just use regular string operations:

```js
let shareCommonSubstring = (str1, str2) => [...str2].some(c2 => str1.includes(c2));

let test = (str1, str2) => console.log(str1, str2, shareCommonSubstring(str1, str2));
test('xyz', 'abc'); // false
test('xyz', 'abcx'); // true
test('axyz', 'abc'); // true
```

But if you insist on regex:

```js
let shareCommonSubstring = (str1, str2) => !!str1.match(new RegExp(`[${str2}]`));

let test = (str1, str2) => console.log(str1, str2, shareCommonSubstring(str1, str2));
test('xyz', 'abc'); // false
test('xyz', 'abcx'); // true
test('axyz', 'abc'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
var subString = 'Hello';
var string = 'Hello World'
var isSubstring = new RegExp(subString).test(string);
```